# Change BoxView color on Tap

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a `BoxView` that I want to change the color of when the user taps it.  I created a `BoxView` called tapView and set the `GestureRecognizer` like so:

```
var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => {
    // handle the tap
    OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(s, e);
};
tapView.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
```

and my method to handle the tap:

```
void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var box = (BoxView)sender;
    box.Color = Color.Red;
}
```

However this doesn't actually change the color on the Tap.  Debugging and stepping through the code it does actually update the `BoxView` color in the code but not on the screen.  What do I need to do to make this actually update the color when touched?

Comment: try using Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread() to be sure you're using the UI thread

Comment: I added this inside my .Tapped handler but still no luck, behaves exactly the same.

Comment: I test your code on my side and it works fine, would you mind post more complete code so that we could reproduce this problem on our side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution, assuming you give your BoxView the following property in your XAML `x:Name="myBox"`

```
//This code betlow the page InitializeComponent call
var boxTapHandler = new TapGestureRecognizer();
boxTapHandler.Tapped += ChangeColor;
myBox.GestureRecognizers.Add(boxTapHandler);
```

Change color method, similar, though referencing the BoxView by name

```
private void ChangeColor(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    myBox.Color = Color.red;
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but the color still doesn't change on tap.  It works just like my original does and correctly steps through and updates the color in code, but the screen doesn't change color.

Comment: Is it possible you're altering the colour again somewhere else in the code after this? Try this code in a new page, it should work. Alternatively, you could try using a grid, and attaching this tap handler to the grid, modifying it's `BackgroundColor` property.

Answer (score 0):

So I discovered as standalone code this works ok, but in my MVVM app it does not.  I wound up creating a box on top and changing the opacity on a tap worked just fine.